# Configure inArguments and outArguments

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, databinding

I am trying to get the outArgument from 1 custom activity to be the inArgument of another.  I have looked at the Desk.com example with creating and updating a case but have been unable to translate that into my activities.  After the interaction has been saved, not activated, I have done an API call to view the interaction.  The outArguments for the first custom activity is:

`"outArguments": [{
   "targetingID": "text"
 }]`

The inArguments for the second activity is:

`"{{Interaction.REST-1.targetingID}}"`

REST-1 is the correct ActivityKey for the first custom activity but I get the following error message:

`Activity REST-2 of type REST has an argument targetingID which is not a valid argument`

Is there something I am missing in order to get these activities "synced up"?

Comment: Looks OK to me, are you able to share the public URLs to your config.json files for both of your custom activities?

Comment: Yes, here are both config.json files and the saved interaction that I pulled back from the API.  
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5e399d43496c0998f149a76ceaead4b9

Comment: In your [second activity config.json](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5e399d43496c0998f149a76ceaead4b9#file-second-activity-config-json) try changing `"inArguments": [{"targetingID": ""}],` to `"inArguments": [{"targetingID": "{{Interaction.REST-1.targetingID}}"}],`

Comment: I had tried that in the past and still gave me the same error message.  Through Postmonger I am able to find and append the CustomerKey to the data binding for the inArguments.  Do you know where the custom activities look for the outArguments?  Is it in the config,json or in the payload after the activity is configured?

Comment: That's a good question, sorry I'm not sure. From the create/update case example, it appears that it looks in the config.json file (which is just plain stupid as the Activity Key will change).

Comment: Have you tried implementing the desk.com create/update case example? Does this work for you? It worked perfectly when I tried last year but perhaps something has changed. That's what I would try next...

Comment: I ended up speaking directly with the developers at Salesforce and they determined that I was missing the schema for both of the REST activities.  The dataTypes of the 2 activities are compared when using an outArgument from one activity as the inArgument in another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use the outArgument from one REST activity as an inArgument for another REST activity the schema is required.  The schema is needed to compare the data types of the value being passed.

The config.json using the inArgument needs to have
`"schema": {
   "arguments": {
     "execute": {
       "inArguments": [
         {
           "key": {
             "dataType": "Text",
             "isNullable": false,
             "direction": "In"
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
 }`

The config.json using the outArgument needs to have
`"schema": {
   "arguments": {
     "execute": {
       "outArguments": [
         {
           "key": {
             "dataType": "Text",
             "isNullable": false,
             "access": "Visible",
             "direction": "Out"
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
 }`